# Embed an MHTML file in an email using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, mhtml, sp-send-dbmail

I'm currently sending a report from SSRS in MHTML using a subscription so that it gets embedded in the body of the email.

I want to get similar functionality using sp_send_dbmail so that I can change the email via SQL code, however when I send the MHTML file as an attachment it is not embedded in the email body.

How can I embed the MHTML in the email body using sp_send_dbmail?

EDIT: for those asking why I want to do this instead of using a subscription, it is to integrate two existing processes in an enterprise environment. One process sends emails, the other generates report files.

Comment: but why you are sending using sp_send_dbmail ??? if you want to send customized mail then better way to use "New Data-driven Subscription"...

Comment: but why?! if you want to send the report from sql, use reportserver.dbo.addevent procedure.

Comment: why ask why?  I currently have two independent processes: one that uses dbmail to send emails and another that generates MHTML files. I want to integrate the MHTML file from one process into the other process.

Comment: @FistOfFury you got answer on that ?